# Add Progressive Web Apps to App drawer/Tray

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, progressive-web-apps

How can I make a progressive web app to be added to the app drawer, not restricted to only the home screen. this is my manifest file. An example is the twitter web app, it can be added to the home screen and app drawer too. I don't know if there is something I should add to this web manifest.

```
{
"name": "Weather",
"short_name": "Weather",
"icons": [{
  "src": "images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
    "sizes": "128x128",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
    "sizes": "144x144",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
    "sizes": "152x152",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
    "sizes": "192x192",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "images/icons/icon-256x256.png",
    "sizes": "256x256",
    "type": "image/png"
  }],
 "start_url": "/index.html",
 "display": "standalone",
 "background_color": "#3E4EB8",
 "theme_color": "#2F3BA2"
}
```

Comment: What version of chrome are you using on your phone? According to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen) from Chrome 59 onwards it should create and install an APK automagically and appear in the app drawer. May also be affected by not running stock Android e.g. Samsung's UI etc.

Comment: Tested on a couple of Samsung devices and it works. So, the problem shouldn't be related to a device vendor.

Answer (score 0):

You need no define a `scope` property in the manifest file and use Chrome v59 or above:
https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#scope-member

See the docs of improved "Add to Home screen":
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my chrome browser and define a scope property in the manifest file, an